# change log in button to user name ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I make it so when a user logs in the log in button is changed to their email in the nav bar

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
  @guestaccount = Guestaccount.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
  if @guestaccount && @guestaccount.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
   session[:guestaccount_id] = @guestaccount.id
redirect_to '/guest?'
else
flash.now[:danger] = "Invalid email/password combination"
  render 'new'
end 
end

def destroy 
  session[:guestaccount_id] = nil 
  redirect_to '/guest?' 
end
end
```

this is my nav bar

```
<%= button_to "Returning Guest ", guestlogin_path,  :method => "get", class: "button round success" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% if session[:guestaccount_id] %>
  <%= Guestaccount.find(session[:guestaccount_id]).email %>
<% else %>
  <%= button_to "Returning Guest ", guestlogin_path,  :method => "get", class: "button round success" %>
<% end %>
```

Will do it. Feel free to adjust styling and content within the if/else blocks. If you have a `current_user`, `current_guestaccount`, or similar method, I would use that instead of the session and `.find` call.

You can define a `current_guestaccount` method in your `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ...

  # Use this before internal/non-request (index/show/create/etc) controller methods
  protected

  # Usable in your controllers. E.g. authentication, loading associated data.
  def current_guestaccount
    # Return nil if the session value isn't set, don't query the DB
    return nil unless session[:guestaccount_id]
    # @x ||= y
    # will make y run only once if it returns a successful value,
    # essentially caching it for the entire request
    @current_guestaccount ||= Guestaccount.find(session[:guestaccount_id])
  end
  # This makes current_guestaccount, a controller method, accessible in your views.
  helper_method :current_guestaccount
end
```

Then, in your view you can use

```
<% if current_guestaccount %>
  <%= current_guestaccount.email %>
<% else %>
  <%= button_to "Returning Guest ", guestlogin_path,  :method => "get", class: "button round success" %>
<% end %>
```

Which will use 1 `SELECT` query for the whole request instead of multiple. You can also use classes and HTML nodes within your view:

```
<% if current_guestaccount %>
  <span class="guest-email"><%= current_guestaccount.email %></span>
<% else %>
  <%= button_to "Returning Guest ", guestlogin_path,  :method => "get", class: "button round success" %>
<% end %>
```

To adjust the styling later with CSS.

Comment: so what happens if i dont have the current_guestaccount because thats not gonna work. Because the method you have above works but the way my nav works it dosent let me edit the button on it

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what Benjamin Mann's said, however please do not put ORM queries in the view template...

If the user is logged user should be stored in the controller.

```
<% if current_user %>
    <%= current_user.email %>
<% else %>
    <%= button_to "Returning Guest ", guestlogin_path,  :method => "get", class: "button round success" %>
<% end>
```